# Como executar um alert somente uma vez em uma View Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, javascript-eventos

Tenho um projeto em asp.net mvc e na minha view possui um alert que é executado sempre que a page é carregada (Ele fecha automaticamente). O problema é que toda vez que eu faço um submit e a view é recarregada, o alert aparece. Preciso que ele seja aberto somente quando a page é acessada pela primeira vez. Existe alguma maneira de se fazer isso com JS e preferencialmente sem usar cookies?

HTML

```
<div id="alert-dicas" role="alert" class="alert alert-warning alert-icon alert-dismissible">
    <button id="btn-close-dicas" aria-label="Close" class="close" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    <i class="icon fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h4>Dica</h4>
    <p>
        mensagem aqui...
    </p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#alert-dicas").fadeTo(15000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
        $("#alert-dicas").slideUp(500);
    });

    $('#frmBackupRestore').on('submit', function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();

        if (checkFormValidateOrNotBackupRestore() == true) {
            startLoadOneMoment();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: sem usar cookies? só se gravar a informação no server, num banco de dados, pra saber que já foi exibido

Comment: Hum, não consigo pensar em algo que não necessite guardar o estado da requisição.
Já pensou em utilizar o localStorage?

Comment: outra opção é fazer como o @RicardoPontual comentou.

Comment: vai ter de usar um repositório para salve, cookies, como o @GeiltonXavier comentou localstorage, um banco de dados... se não precisar ser realmente uma única vez, pode usar uma session, ai ao menos durante a sessão não vai aparecer novamente, só quando fechar o navegador ou expirar a sessão

Comment: Acho que usar o database tb não seria muito viável para meu caso... Como fazer isso usando session?

Answer (score 1):

**1º Método - Session**

Você pode fazer essa verificação usando `Session` através de códigos `Razor` na sua página, adicionando uma condição simples:

```js
@if (Session["MostrouAlerta"] == null)
{
  Session["MostrouAlerta"] = true;
  {...}
}
```

Mas desta maneira toda vez que perder a sessão ele vai entrar na condição novamente.

**2º Método - Cookies**

Para fazer através de cookies para que não exiba mais nem depois de perder a sessão faça da seguinte maneira:

Adicione no seu `javascript` que mostra/esconde o alerta o código para armazenar o valor no `cookie`:

```js
document.cookie = "mostrouAlerta=true";
```

Depois faça a mesma condição para imprimir o código na sua página usando `Razor`:

```js
if (Request.Cookies["mostrouAlerta"].Value== "true")
{
  {...}
}
```